# List Object comparison

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am retrieving a List of customers refs storing it in a string format:

```
List<string> CustomerRefs(); //List of customer refs
```

I add a customer to the list by

```
List<Customer> CustomersList = new List<Customer>();

foreach (string CustRef in CustomerRefs)
{
  Customer c = new Customer();
  c.ref = CustRef;
  CustomersList.Add(c);
}
```

I then want to check if we already have this customer on our database. If not then send an email. `CurrentCustomers` is a List from my DB with **our current customers**

```
                foreach (Customer cm in CustomersList)
                {
                    if (!CurrentCustomers.Contains(cm))
                    {
                        //Email someone
                    }
                }
```

Now the list contains the same ref but it continues to reach `//Email someone` line.

I have some ideas on why this maybe happening, i THINK it maybe comparing the ID (which is always 0) or the entire object and against the ref which is what i am targetting.

So is there a way of comparing the ref within the object, or have i done something and finally should i instead look for customer in our database, if found, add it to the `CustomersList` and compare it this way?

Please note i have read MSDN and just need some clarification. Perhaps I've read too much into this and not seeing this clearly at the moment.

Comment: That's *not* your code - you've got two different variables called `c`, and you're trying to use a keyword (`ref`) as an identifier. It's really hard to tell what's actually going on if you only provide pseudo-code.

Comment: Typo - amended. Who decided to downvote me? Can you explain why at least?

Comment: I downvoted you because the question was unclear. It's *still* not clear, and it's *still* pseudo-code. And we have no idea wherre `CurrentCustomers` comes from vs CustomerRefs, or whether `Customer` overrides `Equals`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're adding a `string` to a `List<Customer>` that would not even compile.

Comment: Well i see an answer below - perhaps it wasnt clear to you but rather than downvote why not just ask for clarification? Some people are to eager to downvote on anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Contains` because you appear to be creating separate instances of your objects even though some of them share the same `ID` and thus logically represent the "same" entities.

Contains is using a default equality comparer which is comparing the object references of the separate instances of `Customer` and failing to return `true`, even in cases where your `Customer` objects have the same `ID`.  You need to compare the `ID` values.  For this, you can use [the `Any` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (Customer cm in CustomersList)
{
    if (!CurrentCustomers.Any((x) => x.ID == cm.ID))
    {
        //Email someone
    }
}
```

The issue bespeaks a potentially bigger problem, though.  You may run into issues if you have separate instances of objects that logically represent the "same" object (e.g. based on a unique ID).  I would suggest maintaining only one instance of each object that is the "same".  For this, you can use an [Identity Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern).

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick. Appreciate your thoughts. There is one instance i just altered the code to demo this as i knew there must be another way.